# What is the best practice for a Stream of one element?

Tags: java

Suppose I have a method

```
void doSomething(int x){
  Stream<Long> stream = someUtil.getSomething(x);
}
```

Suppose I have a utility function `someUtil.getSomeStream(x)`, which returns a stream of at most size 1.

```
class SomeUtil {
  /* Returns Stream<Long>, the stream can have size at most 1 */
  public static Stream<Long> getSomething(x){
    Optional<Long> opt = doSomethingWithXAndReturnOptional(x);
    return opt.map(Stream::of).orElse(Stream.empty());
  }
}
```

The debate I am having is whether to make this method return a `Stream<Long>` which will have at most size 1 versus return an `Optional<Long>`, which the callers will convert like this:

```
void doSomething(int x){
  Stream<Long> stream = Stream.of(someUtil.getSomething(x).get()); //convert to stream ourselves as the caller
}
```

We only have one caller for now `doSomething(int x)` but it would be easier for this caller (and most likely future callers) to expect a Stream. At the same time it could be misleading that we are returning a Stream of size 1 always.

What is the correct, readable, maintainable and least confusing approach here?

Comment: Don't use `get` to get the value from the `Optional`. It will throw an exception if the `Optional` is empty.

Comment: FYI, since Java 9 you can [stream an optional](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html#stream--) directly. And Guava offers `Streams.stream(Optional)`.

Answer (score 1):

This is not an adequate question as it opens a debate.

If you method contract is to return at most 1 value, returning an Optional is much more readable imo.

If you method contract is to stream values, return a Stream is much more readable.

You can use Optional::stream and Stream::findFirst to convert between the two as required.(java 9 https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html#stream--).